# MVC3 with Ajax partial view - how to display "Success" alert when creation was successfull?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, alert, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have an "Advanced Search" view. The filters configuration is an ajax partial view and the search results list is another one. On the filters configuration partial view I have a "Search" button and a "Save your search filter" submit button. I would like to display an alert saying "Save was successful" if the filter was saved in the DB, otherwise no alert at all, since any error is displayed in the dedicated area.

This is what I have so far:

AdvancedSearch.cshtml

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.MyViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Advanced search";
}

<div id="divUpdateable">
    @Html.Partial("_Filters", Model)
</div>
<div id="divList">
    @Html.Partial("_SearchResults", Model.ResultsList)
</div>
```

_Filters.cshtml

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.MyViewModel
<script type="text/javascript">
function ExecuteSearch() {
    getForm(window.location.pathname + '/ListResults?
    '&City=' + $("#txtCity").val() +
    '&pCountry_ID=' + $("#ddlCountry").val() +
    '&pPriceMin=' + $("#txtPriceMin").val() +
    '&pPriceMax=' + $("#txtPriceMax").val() +
       , 'divList');
}
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddOrUpdateFilter", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "divUpdateable",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    OnSuccess = "ExecuteSearch",
}, new { id = "idformCreate" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Some errors occured, please correct and retry.")
    <p>@Html.ValidationMessage("_FORM")</p>
    <div class="validation-summary-errors">
        <span></span>
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </div>

    ... controls...

    <input id="SearchButton" type="button" value="Search" onclick="ExecuteSearch();" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input id="SaveButton" type="submit" value="Save your search filter" />
}
```

I would like to have a function to call on "OnSuccess" instead of the "ExecuteSearch" function, something like this:

```
function OnSuccessDoThis() {
    alert("Your filter was successfully saved");
    ExecuteSearch();
};
```

But in this form, the alert displays even if there are errors displayed in the "validation" area. How to express a condition for displaying the alert?

Answer (score 0):

If http responde code is in range of 200 or 304 then it is considered successful. And onSuccess callback is called, in your case it happens alwayes because your controller is returning a valid page with code 200. You have to look with jQuery (within onSuccess callback) if there are divs with errors (e.g. count them) and if there is none it means success.

I don't remember exacly what class they have, but it would look like this:

```
if($("div.ErrorMessage").length > 0) { //or span.field-validation-error
  // success
} else {
  // failure
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I am not sure if I can apply your suggestion, since the errors I am talking about are in fact failures of the business rules, for instance: the user is not logged in, or the user has not the privileges for saving a certain kind of filter, or some filter combinations are not allowed...

Comment: jQuery talks HTTP. It knows nothing about business rules and stuff. So make your server return proper status code and then use the OnSuccess and OnFailure callbacks. Or as 0lukasz0 suggested, if you can't make your application more RESTful you could do some HTML scraping in jQuery to detect if the server returned a partial containing some error.